# How can I let iPhone users watch videos on my website with subtitles?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

There is a task to do on the website watching videos with subtitles (external).

Has anyone done this in the video player on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the first answer doesn't go, 'cause  [please confirm] we're talking about html page, not native app;
in case, ther's this [library](http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/);; I would give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Since a subtitles file is basically just a text file with a collection of data comprising of parameters - `to-time`, `from-time` and `text-to-show`, you can display this data in a subview (a simple `UILabel` would suffice) over `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view. From the subtitles file (eg. a `.srt` file), create an array of `Subtitle` objects with these three class variables. Then, you can set up a chain of `NSTimer`s that will be fired after the showing time of a `Subtitle` object is completed or when the next `subTitle` needs to be shown.

**EDIT-** This answer was meant for native video playing with subtitles. I didn't read through the website part but I still think this answer is relevant because the idea stays the same, be it HTML+JS or native iOS.